Segfault in Boost::python object converter after updating to boost 1_83_0
I have a python library written in c++ and specifically a function that retrieves a value from a redis server using boost async io:
    python::object redis::connexion::py_mget(python::object keys) {
        int size = python::extract<int>(keys.attr("__len__")())();
        std::vector<python::object> objects(size);
        std::string error;

        // we need to protect the python GIL from multithreaded access
        unsigned int todo = size;
        std::mutex mutex;
        std::condition_variable condition;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

        for(auto i : xxs::range(size)) {
            const auto& key = python::extract<redis::key>(keys[i])();
            (*this)(
                [&,i] (std::unique_ptr<xxs::redis::value> value) {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
                    /* This next line throws segfault */
                    objects[i] = key.read(std::move(value)); 
                    if(!--todo) condition.notify_one();
                },
                [&] (const std::string& msg) {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
                    error = msg;
                    if(!--todo) condition.notify_one();
                }
            ) << redis::get(key.name());
        }

        while(todo) condition.wait(lock);
        if(!error.empty()) THROW(error);
        return python::make_list(objects);
    }

where key.read calls this function:
virtual python::object read(std::unique_ptr<xxs::redis::value> value) const override {
    if(value->is_null()) return python::object();
    if(!value->is_blob()) THROW("Invalid value stored in REDIS")
    auto pos = value->blob().seekg();
    xxs::object obj;
    obj.read(pos);
        /* This function throws the Segfault */
    return python::object(obj);
}                   

Now, keep in mind:

If I isolate the function key.read(std::move(value)) and I used it without a loop, it actually works. However, when I put it in the original context with the async io and the mutexes, then it throws a Segfault (core dumped).
It was all fine with boost 1_79_0, python 3.10, ubuntu 22.04, clang. It became a problem with boost 1_83_0 (also with boost 1_84_0, and boost 1_85_0) and python 3.12 and ubuntu 24.04.

The valgrind output is completely unreadable...
Please help me, I'm quite clueless and helpless!
I have tried to use
PyGILState_STATE gstate; gstate = PyGILState_Ensure(); PyGILState_Release(gstate); 
in several different places to see if I could improve things. The only thing it managed to was to create deadlocks.

The mutex/condition are a local variable. By definition it will not synchronize anything unless you are causing multiple threads to run locally. Likely they both need to be global (or at least class members). This could have happened when e.g. copy pasting the code from some source that assumed it was "obvious" where the declarations should go?

Hi, thank you so much for your reply.  Where you see "<< redis::get(key.name())" , that is actually a request sent to redis via tcp/ip by using the boost ASIO framework. I guess that's what starts a thread for the request and a thread for the reply.
I guess the authors wanted to avoid that multiple calls of py_mget from different sources would compete for the underlying resource.
I really don't understand why it was working before the update and now it doesn't.
